# Qt: TreeView and Data Model

Tags: qt, model-view-controller, treeview

I have a Qt Application where I use a TreeView to display some stuff in a list. Currently, I have three columns: one with an index, a number and a string. My data model looks as follows:

```
struct item
{
    int a;
    QString b;
    bool c;
};

class DataModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{

private:
    QMap<int, struct item> mymap;

public:
    DataModel(QObject *parent = 0) : QAbstractTableModel(parent) { }
    ~DataModel() { }

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
    {
        return this->mymap.keys().count();
    }

    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
    {
        return 3;
    }

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
    {
        if (!index.isValid())
                return QVariant();

            if (role == Qt::TextAlignmentRole)
            {
                return int(Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignVCenter);
            }
            else if(role == Qt::DisplayRole)
            {
                QList<int> keys = mymap.keys();
                int i = index.column();
                int key = keys.at(index.row());

                switch(i)
                {
                case 0:
                    return key;

                case 1:
                    return mymap.value(key).a;

                case 2:
                    return mymap.value(key).b;
                }
            }
            return QVariant();
    }

    QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation /* orientation */, int role) const
    {
        if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
        {
            switch(section)
            {
                case 0:
                return QString("#");

                case 1:
                return QString("pos");

                case 2:
                return QString("file");

            }
        }
        return QVariant();
    }

    bool setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role)
    {
/* what to do here? */
    }

    void insert(int i, struct item it)
    {
        /* how to update the treeview without losing selection or scroll state? */
       this->mymap.insert(i, it);
    }

    void update(int i, const QString& k)
    {
        /* how to update the treeview? */
    }

};
```

The treeview works correctly if I add some data to the data model before calling `treeView->setModel(&mydatamodel)`. However, how can I actually update the treeview at runtime by adding new items? how can I preserve the current scroll and selection state of the treeview?
Further, you may notice that there is a further field in the item struct which is a bool. How could I display the boolean value as a checkbox? preferably in column 0.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the setData function in the Qt Address Book Example. Take note of the "emit dataChanged" they do in it, this function signals the view to rerender the model.
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-addressbook-example.html

This example will also be present in the demo's and examples QtCreator, if you installed them.

However, for a simple list or tree, I would highly recommend using QStandardItem and QStandardItemModel, it will make things a lot easier!